# Changing the labelling of the numbers in the plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create IDL-like plots in python. I have come close to doing so by changing some of the details in the matplotlibrc file in the matplotlib directory. The following is what I have changed my matplotlibrc file to look like from the standard matplotlibrc file:

```
     ### MATPLOTLIBRC FORMAT

backend      : tkagg

### LINES
lines.linewidth   : 1.1     # line width in points
lines.color       : black   # has no affect on plot(); see axes.color_cycle

### FONT
font.family         : sans-serif
font.weight         : ultralight
font.size           : 12.0
font.sans-serif     : Avant Garde

### TEXT

### LaTeX customizations. See http://www.scipy.org/Wiki/Cookbook/Matplotlib/UsingTex
text.usetex         : True  # use latex for all text handling. The following fonts
                              # are supported through the usual rc parameter settings:
                              # new century schoolbook, bookman, times, palatino,
                              # zapf chancery, charter, serif, sans-serif, helvetica,
                              # avant garde, courier, monospace, computer modern roman,
                              # computer modern sans serif, computer modern typewriter
                              # If another font is desired which can loaded using the
                              # LaTeX \usepackage command, please inquire at the
                              # matplotlib mailing list

mathtext.fontset : custom # Should be 'cm' (Computer Modern), 'stix',
                       # 'stixsans' or 'custom'

### AXES
axes.facecolor      : white   # axes background color

### TICKS
xtick.major.size     : 6      # major tick size in points
xtick.minor.size     : 3      # minor tick size in points
xtick.major.width    : 1    # major tick width in points
xtick.minor.width    : 1    # minor tick width in points

ytick.major.size     : 6      # major tick size in points
ytick.minor.size     : 3      # minor tick size in points
ytick.major.width    : 1    # major tick width in points
ytick.minor.width    : 1    # minor tick width in points

### GRIDS
legend.numpoints     : 1      # the number of points in the legend line
legend.frameon       : False   # whether or not to draw a frame around legend

### FIGURE
figure.figsize   : 4, 4    # figure size in inches
figure.dpi       : 100      # figure dots per inch
figure.facecolor : none    # figure facecolor; 0.75 is scalar gray
figure.edgecolor : white   # figure edgecolor

### SAVING FIGURES
savefig.dpi         : 1000      # figure dots per inch
savefig.format      : ps      # png, ps, pdf, svg
savefig.bbox        : tight # 'tight' or 'standard'.
```

An example of a plot that is produced from these changes is shown. Notice that the output (i.e., the plot) labels the x and y axes with Avant Garde (as specificied in matplotlibrc), but the numbers are not Avatn Garde type. How can I make the numbers the same type font as the labels in the plot, so that both are Avant Garde? Also, is there a way to make the font narrower (thinner), so that the words 'Initial Velocity' are quite thin thin ([i.e., like Hershey vector fonts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcFN1.png))?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the line

```
text.latex.preamble : \usepackage{sfmath}
```

in your `.matplotlibrc` file. This tells latex to use sans-serif fonts for math-text, which is what it uses for tick labels.

Comment: I thank you. Need I download the sfmath package? Where should it be placed once downloaded?

Comment: Its possible, if you don't already have it. You can get it from CTAN [here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/sfmath). You can either have it in the local directory where you run your script, or install it in the usual manner into your `TeX` distribution

Answer (score 0):

Try to download this TTF font which is a replicate of the IDL's default Hershey font https://github.com/yangcht/Hershey_font_TTF. Set `text.usetex : False` and use this Hershey font.

Here is an example of the result:

[image]